# Cloudflare and Opencart ajax and javascript getting session problems

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, opencart

I have added cloudflare on my opencart 1.5.6.4 installation and set it up, just that it keeps logging me out and doesn't let me upload product images, I get a message with regarding to invalid token session when I open the Browse Images from Products->Insert->Data. If I pause cloudflare everything is getting back to normal(not getting logged out anymore and can upload images). Has anyone encountered this issue. I read in the OC forums about this just that in my case happens when cloudflare is active.

Comment: **286** rep and yet does not know that he has to put some code in the question...?

Comment: @shadyyx What code should I put in this case, because it's quite a general issue with regarding to sessions.

Comment: Also when I try to go and browse to the image manager I get an alert with an error like SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

Comment: Maybe a code how do you initialize that cloudflare and how it is being invoked/accessed.

Comment: @shadyyx c;oudflare is a cdn that adds automatically what needed to files. I simply have pointed it to the name servers, got activated, got speed improvement, just that Token Session Issues because of this. In the error.log I don't see any error.

Comment: Hi,

Is the admin area restricted by IP address(es)? If you don't have something like mod_cloudflare installed, our IPs will show in the logs and that could be a factor here. Information about mod_cloudflare at: https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads